# Java upload file to server php

Tags: java, upload

my problem is very strange, i have one class "Uploader", when i implement this class and start the upload the code not go on and stopped with no errors, project for java 1.6:

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.HttpMultipartMode;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;



public class Upload extends SwingWorker<Integer, String> {

    private String urlToConnect = "";
    private String filename = "";
    private String HMPpass = "";
    private String sPass = "";

    public Upload(String server, String filename, String HMPpass, String sPass){

        this.urlToConnect = server;
        this.filename = filename;
        this.HMPpass = HMPpass;
        this.sPass = sPass;

    }

     @Override
      protected Integer doInBackground() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Mi preparo per l'upload di " + this.filename + " su " + this.urlToConnect);

        if(this.urlToConnect.length() < 1 || this.filename.length() < 1)return 0;

        try{

            File fileToUpload = new File(this.filename);
            if(!fileToUpload.exists())return 0;

            System.out.println("Il file esiste !"); // the code stop here with no error      

            //HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(this.urlToConnect);
            System.out.println("Creo gli oggetti !");

            MultipartEntityBuilder multipartEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
            multipartEntity.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
            System.out.println("Riferimento al browser !");

            //multipartEntity.addPart("fileToUpload", new FileBody(new File(this.filename)));
            multipartEntity.addTextBody("HMP", this.HMPpass);
            multipartEntity.addTextBody("arg", this.sPass);
            multipartEntity.addTextBody("cmd", "upload");

            multipartEntity.addBinaryBody("fileToUpload", fileToUpload);

            post.setEntity(multipartEntity.build());
            System.out.println("Preparo la chiamata !");

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

            System.out.println("File inviato ! " + result);
            client.close();

            return 1;

        }catch(Exception e){

            System.out.println("Errore durante il caricamento");
            return 0;

        }

     }

}
```

and response after i use this :

```
Mi preparo per l'upload di C:\test.txt su http://localhost/uploader.php
Il file esiste !
```

the code stopped here and no have a errors, excuse me for my bad English.

Comment: There are 2 lines between the print that works and the one that doesn't work. Use the debugger to check which line is hanging.

Comment: i am in try{} and no errors fired

Comment: You didn't do what I said.

Comment: i have removed try{} statement and no errors fired in debug mode, firewall ? antivirus ?

Comment: "Use the debugger to check which line is hanging". Do you know how to check step by step with a debugger?

Comment: @user1803551 i am in debug mode line by line in eclipse, and no errors found, if you want help me compile this class and test it.

Comment: *"the code stopped here"* Which line exactly? You still did not answer my initial question.